# ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve […]. What is the meaning of this error? Details below

Tags: boot, acpi

When I am turning off my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04, some error message pops up for 1 second on a black screen and then the system shuts down completely. The error message is given below:

```
    [1313.911389] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): could not resolve symbol [\DPPP\, AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/psargs-330)
    [1313.911483] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM.IDSP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200520/psparse-529) 
    [1313.011555] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
```

It was not showing before. Although the system works fine and no visible changes are noticeable, the error message is weird to me. Can anybody please provide me the meaning of this error? Why the error is popping up and how can I resolve it? Do I even need to resolve it? Image of the error message below. Thanks!

[Error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8xiH.jpg)

Comment: Have you seen this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443398/acpi-bios-error-ae-not-found